# Can't add Alamofire to project with cocoapods

Tags: xcode, xcode6, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying add Alamofire to my project using Cocoapods, doing the same thing in the quick start, changing pods file, but still can't import Alamofire.

Is there something that I must more to do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CocoaPods written in Swift, you must explicitly include **use_frameworks!** in your Podfile to opt into using frameworks. Like this:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '2.0'
```

Without including this you’ll get an error when you try to install the pods like Alamofire.